# GPS calculations under $L^p$ norms

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polynomials, norms, resultants

GPS calculations require finding a sphere externally tangent to
four given spheres, an
[Apollonian problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius)
in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
The center of that fifth sphere is one of the $16$ possible solutions to
the Apollonian problem, only two of which touch the given four from outside.
These equations are generally solved via resultants.

I was wondering what would be the GPS calculations under, say, the $L^3$ norm,
which measures the length of a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as
$$
\|x\|_3 = \sqrt[3]{|x_1|^3 + |x_2|^3 + |x_3|^3} \;.
$$
And in particular:

> ***Q***. How many solutions are there to the Apollonian problem under the 
>   [$L^p$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions):
>   Given $d{+}1$ $L^p$-spheres in dimension $d$, find another sphere tangent to
>   those $d{+}1$ spheres. How many externally tangent solutions?

---

[image: GPSinL3]

          

<sup>Three circles under the $L^3$ norm, and a 4th externally tangent
to the 1st three.</sup>

---

---